# Multi tenant app with shared data and dynamic tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema, multi-tenant, entity-attribute-value

I want to create a multi tenant app, but I have never worked with multi tenancy apps.
I would create a database global database for users and some data like zipcodes, countries, ...
And each tenant has his own database so they can store their data on their own server.
Now I have 2 problems:

1. If I connect to the user database I need to access to the shared
   (global data), e.g. zipcode - is this possible?
2. I would create
   dynamic forms, so the users have a table for the forms and the
   fields and a datatable. The advantage of this method is that each
   user can modify his forms, but is this a good practise?

Normally you have fixed table schemas like: customers (id, name, ...), addresses, so on.
Is there any better idea?
Hope someone know's what I mean and can help me :)

Thanks
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1):

mysql "databases" aren't real databases - they're just schemas inside one database.

You can query between schemas, and have foreign keys between schemas too. Just use the fully-qualified name: `schema_name.table_name`.

Dynamic tables (EAV) are almost always a bad idea. Use [existing data model patterns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831) first. If you really, really must use user-defined fields, then follow Martin Fowler's [advice](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html).